# Async in C#: Increased complexity in identifying and synchronizing shared ressources?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I try to get familiar with the async/await keywords in C#.

I learned so far, that attempting to call an async function from a non-async function is a very bad idea as it depends on the called function how to avoid deadlocks.

So you must use the await keyword which in turn requires your own method to be async, which causes the keyword to propagate up to an event handler or main. So far so doable.

The issue I now do not understand: Any await I used along the way could cause the awaited function to execute in a different thread, so I must ensure all functions are side effect free or access ressources synchronized.

So suddenly each member variable of any class must be synchronized. Static variables are suddenly a no-go (well, thats probably for the better). Passing reference types to functions becomes risky. In essence you have to double check and think about each variable in your code.

And guess what? Locks are not possible. I must use something like SemaphoreSlim, which is not re-entrance able. Keeping track of all possible thread spawns to get this right seems challenging to me.

And all that because I must call a library which only offers async functions. I was happy with my synchronous, single threaded point tool...

Any hint how to avoid this excessive amount of work heading towards me? Probably not thinking about multithreading in a single threaded app was a bad idea from me from the start?

Comment: Different thread does not necessarily mean "at the same time". It depends on how you implement stuff, but yes, depending on *why* you introduce tasks it *might* entail more synchronization or writing stuff properly thread-safe.

Comment: You're over-exaggerating slightly. You only need to synchronise access to resources if multiple threads might access them *at the same time*. If you write asynchronous code such that there's only one thing actually executing at a time (which is what happens if you `await` each `Task` straight away, for example), then you won't need extra synchronization. If you write async code which can do multiple things at the same time, then you may need to start synchronising things, but it's better to structure code such that the parallel bits don't have side-effects

Comment: Note also that, while sync-over-async is generally bad practice, you'll only get deadlocks if you're synchronously blocking something like a UI thread. If you've got e.g. a fully synchronous console application (where the main thread doesn't have a `SynchronizationContext` installed on it), you won't deadlock. If you *do* have something like a UI thread, then awaits will marshal back to that thread, and you'll stay single-threaded

Comment: Agreed. If your app was single-threaded in the synchronous version, it is probably trivial to convert it to a simple async version that may physically run on more than one thread, but never with more than one thread doing work at any one time.

Comment: Regarding your final statement, I'd say that whether you need to consider multithreading or not depends on the goal of the application. Note that todays computers have many cores, and a single-threaded application will by itself only use 1 of those cores, so on a 8-core computer, at most you can run at 1/8th of the maximum speed of the cpu. This might be all you need, but being aware of this might guide you to make the right decision regarding multithreaded or not for your application.

Comment: "attempting to call an async function from a non-async function is a very bad idea" - No, that's not true. At some point that has to happen for the code to run.

Comment: The `async`/`await` keywords reduce the need to do synchronization between threads, not increase it. The key thing is to know when you might still need to, but generally the code just works like the sync version.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answers! I now realized, that if I await all tasks right away I am effectively still single threaded regarding synchronisation. So its managable.

For the record: I do not like to be forced to restructure my app to accomodate a library. Having no fool proof way to encapsulate async in sync code is from my point of view a design flaw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any await I used along the way could cause the awaited function to execute in a different thread

To clarify, `await` doesn't cause code to run on a different thread. However, when the code resumes executing *after* the `await`, [it will run on a "context"](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), which may be the thread pool context, in which case it will continue running on a potentially different thread.

> so I must ensure all functions are side effect free or access ressources synchronized.

The purpose of `await` is to free up the calling thread so it can do other things. If those "other things" are accessing the same objects, then yes, you will need synchronization.

As you adopt `async`, you'll find it is more natural to return results instead of causing side effects. Asynchronous code in general (including `async` code) gently pushes you towards a functional programming style.

> So suddenly each member variable of any class must be synchronized. Static variables are suddenly a no-go... Passing reference types to functions becomes risky. In essence you have to double check and think about each variable in your code.

No, this does not necessarily follow.

An `async` method may change threads during its execution, but `await` inserts proper thread synchronization barriers so that you don't have to think about it at that level. All variable access works the same way as synchronous code.

> I must use something like SemaphoreSlim, which is not re-entrance able.

[IMO that's a feature](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/recursive-re-entrant-locks.html).